# Linear map from $L^1 \rightarrow L^{\infty}.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lebesgue-integral

I was wondering how I can show that any linear map $T: L^1(\Omega) \rightarrow L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ can be represented as an integral operator

$$T(f)(x):=\int_{\Omega} K(x,y)f(y) dy.$$

Does anybody know how to show this or where this follows from?

Comment: @Ian: I see two problems with that approach: 1) $T(f)(x)$ is not really well defined, since $T(f)$ is an equivalence class of functions. Also, I don't understand your point about the dependence on $x$ (how do you multiply $x\in\Omega$ by the norm?). 2) We probably want $(x,y)\mapsto k(x,y)$ to be jointly measurable. I am not sure how to show/ensure this.

Comment: Would you like a reference or a hint about how to prove it yourself? This is a famous theorem, so if all you need is a keyword I can give it you. I'm refraining to do so right away to avoid spoilers :)

Comment: @DelioM. a reference would be nice, especially if its online available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.2038) you will find your theorem, a sketch of its proof, some historical remarks and a generalisation.